# How can I edit files without them being extracted?

Tags: encryption, editing, password-protection, temporary-files

Currently, I have some files in a .rar file that is password protected. If I open a Notepad file to make some changes, this file will get extracted first, to the winrar Temp folder, and then I can save the file, after making some changes. My problem is, that if I'm accessing this file in my job, for example, and I really do not want someone to see the contents of my files, then what can I do? How can I edit my files without them being extracted to the temp folder? I would like my files to always remain encapsulated within the encryption software and never be extracted to any folder...

Comment: Use an overall encrypted file system, then everything you do is protected.

Comment: It seems to me that opening an encrypted file will open so you can see it and than so can anyone else see. I am not sure if you can achieve what you want.

Comment: @Tetsujin - that's a good idea!

Comment: @John - You have your point... But one thing is being able to copy a file through the network, another diferent thing is to install a keylogger for example, to take prints of the screen...

Comment: You need to clarify what you are hoping to protect yourself against. Any bad actor who has got so far as to install a keylogger would have access to anything & everything you have access to. Right now this is starting to feel like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I will use veracrypt to encrypt my pendrive. Thank you for your sugestion. It's not an XY Problem, I just want to protect myself from some things, not all, because it is not possible.

Comment: What makes it an XY Problem is you are asking about how to achieve something you perceive to be the solution to your problem, instead of asking about how to solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At minimum, the file will end up decrypted in memory (and not "within the software").

I assume your issue is having the decrypted file on disk. You may consider decrypting to an encrypted drive/folder (for example, OneDrive has a "Person Vault" that encrypts the data at rest.)

On a Windows Machine you could consider using a USB drive with BitLocker enabled.

Honestly, if you're only doing minimum edits you could consider just keeping the data on your phone. There are some decent app-based editors.